# My program doesn't run despite all methods being (seemingly) correct. seems to be a problem with the main method?

Tags: java, class, methods

I am a beginning Java programmer, still trying to get used to all the syntax lol. I don't quite understand what I'm doing wrong? I'm running it on Linux if it matters, and my code is below. Any help would be appreciated, I don't want to know the error, rather I want to know whjy it doesn't work.

```
public class AboutMe {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    static void myName (String name){
    }
    static void mySchool (String school){
    }
    static void myAge ( int age){
      System.out.println(
          "My name is" + name + ", and I attend" + school + ". I am" + age + "years old");
    }
    myName(bob);
    mySchool("Hogwarts");
    myAge(18);
  }
}
```

Comment: The first step would be to consistently format your code.  Whitespace matters, and formatting your code to be human-readable will help you, as a human, read and understand it.  After doing that, what specific error or unexpected result do you observe?

Comment: What does "*does not run*" mean? Do you get a compilation error? If so: please [edit] the post, add the compiler error and highlight the line of code causing the compilation error. Does it throw an exception? If so: please [edit] the post, add the stack trace and highlight the line of code causing the exception. Do you observe unexpected behaviour? If so: please [edit] the post, add a [MRE], as we as expected and observed output.

Comment: This is a typical example as to why code format matters: in the code presented, there are method defined within another method. This is not possible in Java.

Comment: The funny thing is that this question got upvoted. This is what a "lol" is.

Comment: @user16320675 so posting a question not using screenshots is now a favor deserving an upvote? Well,.. Okay.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of problems here.  You do need to have a `Main` class and a `main` method.  The second problem is that you're declairing your variables as methods.  The third problem is that you're attempting to use those variable before they're assigned any values.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name;
    String school;
    int age;
    name = "bob";
    school = "Hogwarts";
    age = 18;
      System.out.println(
          "My name is" + name + ", and I attend" + school + ". I am" + age + "years old");

  }
}
```

you can play with this code here: https://www.mycompiler.io/view/2yzZUcm

Comment: in Java you don't need a  `Main` class, just a `main` method with the correct signature/return type (or better no return: `void`)

Comment: @user16320675  Thanks for that.  I'm not adept with Java at all...  I just felt compelled to answer since the OP was getting nothing but a healthy dose of that trademark SO sass.

Comment: @exceptionalexception thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the code, here it is:

```
class Main {

  static void PrintMe(int age, String name, String school){
    System.out.println("My name is " + name + ", and I attend " + school + ". I am " + age + "years old"); 
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrintMe(18,"bob" , "Hogwarts"); 
  }
}
```

the first problem is you have declared the functions inside Main, then didn't use it as a function. I think you misused it as a variable which is declared like this: `String example = "I'm declaring a string!";`

Also, I think your main class name might have to be `Main` (I'm not sure if that's true: I'm not a Java programmer).

And you wrote the command in a function that doesn't have all the variables specified:

> ```
> static void myAge(int age){
>     System.out.println("My name is" + name + ", and I attend" + school + ". I am" + age + "years old"); }
> ```

Even if this function was placed in a valid place, it doesn't have `String name` and `String school`.

Comment: `sorry about my [English]` Don't express sorrow: Accept the help of a spelling/ *language use* checker [to make sure that your question has\[…\]Correct use of English spelling and grammar to the best of your ability](https://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error).